# scrapy how to override the way of how it retrieves the html code

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

Trying to scrape a site with `Scrapy`, which is a very convenient tool, I realised that the page obtains the HTML code through JS API requests and I want to find a way to use a headless browser to override the way which `Scrapy` is obtaining the HTML code

Comment: Scrape the API call instead.

Comment: It's not so easy I can not find how the API call is working

Comment: It sounds like you want Splash

Comment: @pguardiario I think this is the best solution

Comment: See also https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html